# Doing kubectl rollout undo causing current and previous replicasets persists

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rollout

I am using kubectl for kubernetes based deployments.
I created a deployment which gone to crashloopbackoff state. Then for correcting this issue, rolling update is done. But the deployment failed due to OOM. Then if i do a rollout undo, i am seeing current and previous replicasets with the respective pods in failed state. I only need the previous replicasets with running pods. Any points what might have gone wrong. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you describe the new `ReplicaSet`, I believe you should that the replicas will be set to 0. The `Replicasets` are preserved specifically for the purpose of `undo` operations.

Comment: Can you explain exacly what you see, preferably add some outputs form kubectl get pods,rs and steps to replicate the bahaviour.